# How can I get my JIRA installation to use less CPU?

Tags: installation, jira

I am trying to get [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) working on my server. I have it installed, but when I actually start the server, it says that I have exceeded my CPU limit.

How can I configure it to use less CPU or slow it down in some way?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: I did not unfortunately :(